# How to show some value from api in dropdown input field in PrimeNG

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

```
<p-dropdown inputId="projectStatus" class="p-mr-0" [options]="projectStatus" placeholder="Project Status"
            optionLabel="label" (ngModelChange)="onSelectType($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
            <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
              <span [class]="'customer-badge status-' + option.value">{{option.label}}</span>
            </ng-template>
```

API RESPONSE

{name: "xyz", description: "", label: "abc", type: "xyz", is_active: true, …}

Comment: please share your api response as well.

Answer (score 0):

in your ts file, make `projectStatus` that is bound to options (`[options]="projectStatus"` ) equal the list that comes from the api response